# Execute shell script via Jenkins

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, mv

I have a very simple shell script `build-dev.sh`. This is how it looks like:

```
#artifact build script
echo "Running application build for DEV environment"

ng build --deploy-url "js/" --base-href "/my-app-ui/" --configuration=dev
mkdir dist/my-app-ui/js
mv ./dist/my-app-ui/*.{js,svg,css} ./dist/my-app-ui/js
```

It builds the Angular application, then creates a folder `js` and then it moves files with the extensions `js`, `svg` and `css` to this folder.

When I execute this script directly by myself it works perfectly.

The issue is that I want the script to be executed by Jenkins. So I have configured "Execute shell" step in my build. Once the Jenkins job is executed, it fails on the execution of the third line of the script (`mv` command).

```
mv: cannot stat './dist/my-app-ui/*.{js,svg,css}': No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I think it might be related to the fact that I have `.*{js,svg,css}` in my script.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: may be because jenkins actual directory is not the same that when you runs the script. And/or jenkins user may not have permission to do mkdir

Comment: It is the same directory. I accessed the server via SSH and execute the script from the Jenkins workspace directory. And `mkdir` works fine, the folder is created.

Comment: During the ngbuild, are you sure that the "js/" directory is inside ./dist/ directory ? since the deploy url is js/ then all the assets should be created inside js/ directory under current directory. Last step you are trying to move those assets from a different directory. shouldn't it be like mv ./dist/js/*.{js,svg,css} ./dist/my-app-ui/js/ ?? Did you also check the current working directory and where js/ directory is created??

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am still not sure why it does not work, but the problem is in the usage of brackets - `{js,svg,css}`. 
I have replaced the `mv` command with three lines:

```
mv ./dist/my-app-ui/*.js ./dist/my-app-ui/js
mv ./dist/my-app-ui/*.svg ./dist/my-app-ui/js
mv ./dist/my-app-ui/*.css ./dist/my-app-ui/js
```

This works perfectly. It is still some kind of workaround, but it's doing the exactly same, so it works fine for me.

Comment: You may want to investigate whether you are in fact runnimg the same shell when you run directly vs. what Jenkins executes. A common gotcha is ssh agent runs in a non-interactive shell and does not source the agent user's profile. A lot of S/O posts on that, you may have a similar disconnect and that syntax is not supported by the default system non-int shell.